# PayPal REST API SDK: Payment.Get shipping_address deprecated?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The documentation for the PayPal Rest API SDK for .NET indicates the payer_info.shipping_address is deprecated / obsolete.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Source/SDK/Api/PayerInfo.cs

> Obsolete. Use shipping address present in purchase unit.

What would be the correct field to use to retrieve the payer's shipping address then, using the Get method? I don't see any field called purchase unit or the like returned in the Get method.

I should note, it seems the shipping_address is populated correctly still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a response from PayPal MTS and clarified the documentation is from an older version and is wrong.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/123